# Does problem 2-9 of Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds contain an error?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

In Michael Spivak's *Calculus on Manifolds*, problem 2-9, part (a) on page 18 reads as follows:

> Two functions $f,g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ are **equal up to $\mathbf n$th order** at $a$ if
> $$
> \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(a+h)-g(a+h)}{h^n}=0
> $$
> a) Show that $f$ is differentiable at $a$ if and only if there is a function $g$ of the form $g(x)=a_0+a_1(x-a)$ such that $f$ and $g$ are equal up to first order at $a$.

As written, I think the "if" direction is false.

For instance, take $a=0$, and define $f(x)$ as $x$ for $x\neq0$, and as $1$ for $x=0$. Then, $f$ is obviously not differentiable at $0$, but $f$ and the identity function are equal up to first order at $0$.

Question: is my objection correct? If so, I think the problem can be repaired by requiring continuity. If $a\in\mathbb R$, $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is continuous at $a$, and there is an affine map $g$ such that $f$ and $g$ are equal up to first order, then I believe it follows that $f$ is differentiable at $a$.

Comment: I do agree with your analysis.

Comment: Agreed: I expect Spivak means $f$ and $g$ are assumed continuous.